# Selectmenu is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile 1.3.1 and need to use selectmenu to refresh my dropdown, but i always get selectmenu is noot a function.
I am even tried to call in during onchange function, to make sure it's not because the jquery mobile haven't fully loaded, but i get same error.

Anyone know how to solve it?

```
<p> 
    <select class="font12 required" id="channel_code" name="channel_code" onchange="$('#channel').selectmenu('refresh');"> 
        <option value="">Bank Channel</option>
    </select>
 </p>
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? You don't need to call selectmenu refresh during onChange event.

Comment: actually i need to update it during ajax call..but got same error

Comment: What changes are you making to the element `id="channel"`? Can you show the elements HTML. Is it a `select` and is the widget initialized prior to you calling `.selectmenu()`?